# What is the modern equivalent of Ruby’s deprecated `Date.day_fraction_to_time`?

Tags: ruby

- ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin16]

Trying to run [this example](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_Ruby#Calculating_the_Difference_Between_Dates) (modified to debug using `puts` and use an upcoming birthday date):

```
# http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_Ruby#Calculating_the_Difference_Between_Dates
require 'date'

today = DateTime.now
# => #<DateTime: 441799066630193/180000000,-301/1440,2299161>
puts "Today: " + today.to_s

# birthday = Date.new(2008, 4, 10)
birthday = Date.new(2017, 11, 8)
# => #<Date: 4909133/2,0,2299161>
puts "Birthday: " + birthday.to_s

# days_to_go = birthday - today
# puts days_to_go

time_until = birthday - today
# => Rational(22903369807, 180000000)
puts "Time Until: " + time_until.to_s

time_until.to_i             # get the number of days until my birthday
# => 127
puts "Time Until (integer): " + time_until.to_i.to_s

hours,minutes,seconds,frac = Date.day_fraction_to_time(time_until)
# [3053, 46, 57, Rational(1057, 180000000)]

puts "It is my birthday in #{hours} hours, #{minutes} minutes and #{seconds} seconds (not that I am counting)"
# It is my birthday in 3053 hours, 46 minutes and 57 seconds (not that I am counting)
```

But when I try to run it, it breaks at `day_fration_to_time`, because that method is [deprecated](https://apidock.com/ruby/Date/day_fraction_to_time/class):

```
$ ruby birthday.rb
Today: 2017-10-12T15:46:15-04:00
Birthday: 2017-11-08
Time Until: 150774970751/5760000000
Time Until (integer): 26
birthday.rb:24:in `<main>': undefined method `day_fraction_to_time' for Date:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I see there is another method called [`day_fraction`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Date/day_fraction), but I’m not sure how/if to use it to achieve the same result as before.

Answer (score 2):

you can always add it back to your project with:

```
class Date
  def self.day_fraction_to_time(fr)
    ss,  fr = fr.divmod(86_400) # 4p
    h,   ss = ss.divmod(3600)
    min, s  = ss.divmod(60)
    return h, min, s, fr
  end
end
```

Comment: Adding this to the top of my script (after `require 'date'`) results in ``birthday.rb:6:in `day_fraction_to_time': uninitialized constant Date::SECONDS_IN_DAY (NameError)
 from birthday.rb:34:in `<main>'``

Comment: @HughGuiney obviously, you also have to add the [`SECONDS_IN_DAY`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_8_7/lib/date.rb#L319) constant.

Comment: @HughGuiney - I removed the constant for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
seconds = 1234
Time.at(seconds).utc.strftime("%H:%M")
=> "00:20"
```